# How datatable sorting arrow to be permanent means will always show the sorting arrow not on hover. How is it possible in vuejs+vuetify?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable, vuetify.js

i want datatable sorting arrow to show always not on mouse hover in vuejs vuetify. Can i dot through css or any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! The following css should always display the arrows. You can find out what you need to change by right-clicking on the arrow and selecting "Inspect" (in Chrome at least).

```css
  .v-data-table-header__icon {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/alexanderjanke/pen/QWjBgOQ

Comment: added your code in style but arrow is not showing @Rie

Comment: hmm. just tried it on my end and it worked. Can you create a codesandbox/codepen with your example?

Comment: Seems like i had a previous version of vuetify before. Updated the post

Comment: Your post is working fine. when i am inspecting and changed opacity 1 then arrow showing  but when i am writing code in style it is not working. why it is happening? @Rie

Comment: Are you sure you're placing the css in the correct file? It should be in the same file as your <template> </template>. So it is all in one file <template></template> then <script></script> and at last <style></style>. You got it like this?

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. Since the codepen is working it has to be something else which I cannot see right now

Comment: can you tell how can i center a <v-btn> without using <v-card-actions>,<v-flex> . Only there will be <v-btn> and have to make it center in form. @Rie

Comment: Why no flex? `<div class="d-flex justify-center"> Button here </div>`

Comment: actually if use <div> or <v-card-actions> i can not reduce the space between button and last upper field say <v-text-field> @Rie

Comment: It would be best if you create a new post on here since this is a completely new topic. You have to remove some padding if you want to move them closer to each other though. Try and create a separate codesandbox/codepen with just this behaviour and create a new post :)

Comment: Make sure the style tag is not scoped.  Now this works great.  Thx!